# Operand types are incompatible ("float *" and "const char *")

Tags: c, operands

I've started learning C this week and I have a problem. 
I'm trying to let the user enter how many inputs he wants , but the loop will stop when he enter the input -1 . I'm getting the Operand types are incompatible ("float *" and "const char *")   error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void average()
{

    int i;
    float num[100];
    float sum = 0;
    float average = 0;
    int n = sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0]); 
    //printf("Enter the size of the array: \n");
    //scanf("%d" , &n );



    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. Enter number: ",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&num[i]);
        sum+=num[i];

        if (num == "-1")
        {
            break;
        }

    }
      average=sum/n;
      printf("Average = %.2f",average);

    }
```

Comment: `num == "-1"` has two different types on each side of the `==` operator.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if (num == "-1")
```

is not valid, and is the reason the compiler complains. You're treating `num`, which is of type `float [100]`, as a pointer to a character (by comparing it to another pointer to character).

You meant:

```
if (num[i] == -1)
```

You should do this *before* adding `num[i]` to the `sum`, since the sentinel value `-1` should not be part of the total. There's no need to keep an array of the inputs either, and thus no need for `num` to be an array.

Also, strings in C are compared using `strcmp()`, almost never with `==`.

Comment: I thought that neither of num and -1 are strings.

Comment: Also, comparing float numbers with the equality operators is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @ballotra15 `-1` is not a string, `"-1"` is a string.

Comment: @unwind
Thanks for the help . I did it before just like you said , but it still isn't outputting the correct answer.